# Can granite countertops be used as a desktop on a custom desk?

Tags: kitchen-counters

Granite countertops have become quite popular lately.  How is Granite typically fastened to base cabinets?  Would it be suitable to use as a desktop, say with just four legs attached to it (not a full frame like a base cabinet)?  Or would a structure like a base cabinet be needed with a wood frame on all sides underneath to support and fasten the granite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't just try to attach the legs directly to the granite (or really any material used as a work surface). The result will probably be quite unstable.

I'd build a free standing frame and then fix the worktop to that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a silicone adhesive to attach a slab of granite to use as a desktop. As long as the desk itself is sturdy and stable, it shouldn't be an issue. If the desk will be free standing (not attached to a wall), make sure it wont be too top heavy. You don't want your granite tipping over.

Comment: I think trip0d199 wants a desk with simply a desktop and legs, so I don't think gluing legs to a slab of granite would turn out too well.